# Remove space above/below text when highlighted

Tags: html, css, height

In this example I can use line-height and height to remove the white space above and below the text.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700);
span {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Roboto';

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: .75em;
    line-height: .75em;

    background-color: gold;
}

.noselect{
  user-select: none;
}

.upper{
  font-size:20px;
  position:relative;  //EDIT 2
}

.lower::selection { background: none; } //EDIT 1
```

```html
<div><span class='upper'>UPPER</span></div>
<div><span class='lower'>LOWER</span></div>
```

But when I select the text 'LOWER', the highlighted portion is covering part of the 'UPPER' text. So the in this portion, where the UPPPER text is covered, I can't select the upper text.

Is there a way to prevent this. I've considered using z-index to bring the UPPER text on top, but can this be achieved using line-height only? Or any other way?

I also tried using `user-select: none` to prevent text selection but that just prevents any text from being selected even the highlighted area.

Thanks

**EDIT**: Adding `.lower::selection { background: none; }` and `position:relative;` to .lower makes this work.

Comment: I'm able to select both words despite the overlap. What's the actual problem?

Comment: I think OP just wants the "UPPER" text to be visible when you select "LOWER". [I get this result](https://i.imgur.com/MYwAfoX.png). I suppose you can't just remove the background with `::selection { background: none; }` for this particular area?

Comment: Yeah that's kind of what I'm going for. More specifically. I want to be able to select UPPER text while the cursor is in the grey area of the LOWER text that overlaps the UPPER text.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Your suggestion for the ::selection works well. I'll have to test it out a bit more, but it looks good so far. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, this is another custom font issue where the space itself comes from the font

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Adding position: relative to .lower along with your suggestion, makes this work perfectly. If you want to post that as an answer I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @fractal5 Glad to hear that did the trick, added it as an answer below. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion in the comments, my proposal of using `::selection { background: none; }` mixed with OP's use of `position: relative` solves this issue in this particular context:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700);
span {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: .75em;
  line-height: .75em;
  background-color: gold;
}

.noselect {
  user-select: none;
}

.upper {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.lower::selection {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div><span class='upper'>UPPER</span></div>
<div><span class='lower'>LOWER</span></div>
```